# How do I add Bearer Token in RSocket client in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, rsocket, rsocket-java

I am creating an RSocket Client in Spring Boot using Java. I think there is an issue in adding bearer token from the client end. Please help me in this.

This is my client code

```java
Flux<RSocket> clientRSocket = RSocketConnector.create()
            .metadataMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.getString())
            .dataMimeType(WellKnownMimeType.APPLICATION_JSON.getString())
            .keepAlive(Duration.ofMinutes(10), Duration.ofMinutes(10)).payloadDecoder(PayloadDecoder.ZERO_COPY)
            .connect(transport).flux();

    CompositeByteBuf metadata = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.compositeBuffer();

    RoutingMetadata routingMetadata = TaggingMetadataCodec.createRoutingMetadata(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
            List.of("/test"));

    ByteBuf simpleAuthentication = AuthMetadataCodec.encodeBearerMetadata(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
            TenantContext.getCurrentToken().toCharArray());

    CompositeMetadataCodec.encodeAndAddMetadata(metadata, ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
            WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING, routingMetadata.getContent());

    CompositeMetadataCodec..encodeAndAddMetadata(metadata, ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
            WellKnownMimeType.MESSAGE_RSOCKET_AUTHENTICATION, simpleAuthentication.asByteBuf());

    clientRSocket.subscribe(rsoc -> {

        Disposable requestStream = rsoc.requestStream(DefaultPayload.create(data, metadata))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(1, 100, UUID.randomUUID().toString())).map(mapper -> {
                    return mapper.getDataUtf8();
                }).subscribe();
    });
```

Below is the trace of error I am getting at server end at the time of RSocket Security.

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.ReactiveAuthorizationManager.lambda$verify$1(ReactiveAuthorizationManager.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:77)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:851)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1712)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1712)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1713)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:441)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:211)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1712)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCurrentContext.subscribe(MonoCurrentContext.java:35)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:135)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:45)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8264)
    at io.rsocket.internal.RateLimitableRequestPublisher.subscribe(RateLimitableRequestPublisher.java:74)
    at io.rsocket.RSocketResponder.handleStream(RSocketResponder.java:446)
    at io.rsocket.RSocketResponder.handleFrame(RSocketResponder.java:310)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drainRegular(FluxGroupBy.java:554)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:630)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$UnicastGroupedFlux.subscribe(FluxGroupBy.java:696)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8264)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:188)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1712)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:317)
    at io.rsocket.internal.ClientServerInputMultiplexer.lambda$new$1(ClientServerInputMultiplexer.java:116)
    at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drainLoop(FluxGroupBy.java:380)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.drain(FluxGroupBy.java:316)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxGroupBy$GroupByMain.onNext(FluxGroupBy.java:201)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:220)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:353)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:352)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:493)
    at reactor.netty.http.server.WebsocketServerOperations.onInboundNext(WebsocketServerOperations.java:154)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```